# C# Own class inherit PictureBox doesn't display

Tags: c#, picturebox

I'm writing a game, and I created a class which inherits from PictureBox

```
class Mashrooms : System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox
{

   public  Mashrooms(int x, int y)
    {

        Name = "mush";
        Location = new Point(x, y);
        Enabled = true;

         //Image = Image.FromFile("mushroom.png");
        ImageLocation = @"mushroom.png";
         Size = new Size(16,32);

    }

}
```

In form1.Designer.cs I put

```
Mashrooms m = new Mashrooms (200,50);
        this.Controls.Add(m);
```

Even though the game runs, picture is not displayed.

Comment: What happens if you replace it with a normal `PictureBox` with the same code? Are you sure the filename `"mushroom.png"` is sufficient?

Comment: Note that unless you're planning on overriding any behavior of the `PictureBox` class, you're better off not deriving from it and instead either wrapping it (e.g. in a `UserControl`) or putting this logic in your `InitializeComponent` method.

Comment: Are you adding the control to the form?

Comment: I changed order lines of code, it started working.